# CentOS getting unusable slow over time running at Hyper-V

Tags: centos, performance, hyper-v, apache2, twiki

I run TWiki 6.1 on a CentOS Stream 9-virtual machine hosted in Hyper-V at Windows10. VMs hostanme is "twiki"

System ran for over a year now without any problems but since some weeks its not responding anymore and I don't have a clue whats going on.
After rebooting the VM from Hyper-V its running fast and flawless for quite some time (about a day) but after that nothing seems to work at all.
I have several mechanisms to interact with the CentosOS-vm:

- accessing the twiki-pages from within a browser: error "The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application." after hanging several seconds
- using the CentOS adminstrators-webconsole (http://twiki:9090): hangs and gives me "site not found"
- using "ssh twiki" at the console: just hangs forever
- accessing samba-shares from the explorer (\twiki): hangs several minutes bevor saying "unavailable"
- Connecting from Hyper-V-Manager: Doesn't work: It just shows a black Screen, no interaction possible
- Shutdown from Hyper-V-Manager doenst work. After several minutes it shows up an error-message
- Turning off the VM and restarting it works
- There are nightly cronjobs to update usage-statistics and backup the twikisystem. According to /var/log/cron both jobs startet but none of them did something I can see (they have to create some files)

Of course nothing was changed at the VM-Host or the CentOS-guestsystem intentional. They both have automatic updates enabled.
I don't know where to start looking for problems. Can be the Hyper-V system, a misconfigured CentOS, the apacheserver, samba, twiki, perl, ... Are there any hints where to start? What I know is even when the system "hangs":

- "ping twiki" is fast: <1ms
- another VM (Ubuntu) is still working

Some more information:

- Host: Win10 Server, 64Bit, CPU: Intel Xeon Silver 4210R, 10 Cores, 128GB Memory
- Data from Hyper-V: CPU-usage of every VM: 0-3%
- TWiki-VM-Configuration: Memory: 8GB, 2 CPUs
- CentOS Memory consumption while running: 3,2GB, CPU-usage: about 2-10%
- We're a rather small company so there are not many users trying to access the TWiki at the same time

Comment: Add details about disk space usage and swap space usage. Running low on the first causes performance problems, using the second will cause performance problems.

Comment: diskspace: 25,7GB used out of 70GB disk-size
Swap: 0GB used out of 4,27 available
RAM: 3GB used out of 8GB 
https://postimg.cc/R300BT1j